Entropy and the beginning of the universe
In an article titled "Did the Universe Begin? V: The Ordinary Second Law", Aaron Wall presents two scenarios regarding entropy:
"Now, either (a) there was a beginning of time, or (b) the entropy remained more or less at the same value for an infinite amount of time prior to some particular moment;"
Dr. Wall comments on scenario (b):
"Since scenario (b) seems implausible (though not necessarily impossible)"
However, could scenario (b) be realistic? I know that at the beginning of the universe, there was a quark-gluon plasma, which then cooled and formed atoms, and the universe gradually evolved to its current state.
Could there have been adiabatic processes that maintained the entropy in the quark-gluon plasma at a certain level without increasing it?
